# Problem with android studio display language

Tags: android, display

I encountered this weird problem where after installing android studio latest version from official website this strange display language appeared.

please help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWtmw.jpg)

Comment: What language is it supposed to be?

Comment: It should be english but i think this is not even a language i think it is rubbish 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem

it appears that for some reason android studio was using an unsupported font, when I changes the font to Arial everything is ok and the language is correct.

thanks for trying to help me everybody.

cheers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0wAU.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its encoded, every character is replaced by the character 2 places after it..

so NEXT is replaced by PGZV on the screen

You sure you downloaded the correct Android Studio ?

Comment: Yes. I downloaded it from official android studio website. I even tried older version but it is the same problem. I think the problem is in windows or something. 

Comment: Yeah i think u need to change your system language